# On "Select" update open url in new tab... only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webforms, selection

I am using javascript to load a url into a _blank page when the user changes the value of a select dropdown.

```
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
  window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_blank');
};
```

BUT I only want the script to open a new tab once and if they change again open the new page in the tab they previously opened.

Comment: What about maintaining a flag?

Comment: Could you give more feedback on flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether window was opened or not using reference of the window

```
    urlmenu.onchange = function() {
       if (typeof(ref) != 'undefined') {
         ref.location = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value;
       } else {
         ref = window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_blank');
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is supposed to be a name of the newly created window (`_blank` in your case). It is used in HTML `target` attribute to refer the pop-up, *and* in JS to check, if [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) should open a new window/tab, or reload an existing one.

To open a new tab on every call, create an unique window name, using for example a timestamp. To open all new pages in the same tab, give a constant name to window.

Answer (score 1):

```
var isOpen = false;

if(!isOpen){
    urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_blank');
    };
    isOpen = true;
}
```

Try using this, hope I understood correctly.